# Retrieve same column data from two different rows with one sqlite3 query?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table `profiles` containing people with a primary key `login_hash` and a bunch of other fields (for example, `age`). Another table, `msgs`, contains `src` and `dest` fields, both of which are foreign keys to `login_hash` from the `profiles` table. How do I retrieve the ages of the src and dests in one sqlite3 (from Python) query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two inner joins:

```
SELECT m.*, p1.*, p2.*
  FROM msgs m
INNER JOIN profiles p1 ON m.src = p1.login_hash
INNER JOIN profiles p2 ON m.dest = p2.login_hash
```